# Android: how do I connect Studio to Genymotion Virtual Device?

Tags: android, genymotion

I have the Genymotion v1.0.7 plug-in installed in Android Studio v3.3.2.  When I click the Genymotion icon on the Studio toolbar it launches the Genymotion Device Manager dialog.  I select a virtual device and click "Start..." and the device launches in a new dialog and the Status row for the device in the Genymotion Device Manager shows "On".
[image]

Next I click on the Studo "Run" icon and the Select Deployment Target dialog launches but there are no "Connected Devices".  What am I missing here?

[image]

Note that under File/Settings/Plugins the Genymotion plugin is enabled.  But Studio is showing the plug-in icon as greyed out.  Not sure what this means:

[image]

I am using custom ADB using Android SDK Tools in Genymotion:

[image]

Here is the ADB location from within Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I use： adb connect genymontionip:5555

```
adb connect 192.168.145.101:5555
```

genymontion 3.0.2 solve this problem

release note https://www.genymotion.com/product-release-note/desktop/#release-302

Comment: So do not use Studio's Genymotion Device Manager?

Comment: Can use it find IP Address

Answer (score 1):

Go to Genymotion settings, `ADB` tab and set `Use custom Android SDK tools`:

[image]

Then set path to the same SDK your Android Studio instance is using (`Tools` -> `SDK Manager`).

Comment: I am using custom Android SDK tools and have it set to the same path in Studio.  I will update the question to show it.